# In java compare 2 objects of type JSObject using javascript operator '==='

Tags: java, javascript

In java, How to compare 2 java objects of type JSObject using a javascript operator like '==' or '==='?

Comment: there is no any Operator like `===` in java as in javascript this operator is checking `equal value and equal type`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does it matter which equals operator (== vs ===) I use in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: `Java != JavaScript`

Answer (score 0):

**In javaScript**
`object.hasOwnProperty(proName)` tells object `has` or `has not` the `property`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if two variables or instances point to the same object use:

```
if (obj1 === obj2)
```

Or else, if you want to check if the two objects are completely identical with the same properties and methods in the same order and having the same values but not necessarily being the same object, use:

```
if (JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2))
```

If the order in which the properties and methods are attached can be different you'd need to loop through all the properties and methods of both objects and check that a corresponding entry exists for the other. Just looping through all the properties and methods of one wouldn't check that there are no extra properties and methods attached to the other.

Got it from: [codingforums](http://www.codingforums.com)